# Bash script - if and grep won't work

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

As this community seems to be really nice so I thought I'd ask a question -

I have this little script but it won't just grep the timed out from the output:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter ntp server address: "
read SERVER
if ntpdc -n -c monlist $SERVER | grep "timed out"
then 
  echo "Server won't let You use monlist."
  exit 0
else 
  echo "Server will let You use monlist."
fi
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output of `ntpdc -n -c monlist $SERVER` if you run it manually?

Comment: I think you should put brackets around your if arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the "problem" is that `ntpdc` sends the timeout message to standard error, not standard out, so `grep` doesn't see it on the input of the pipe. You can remedy by routing standard error of the `ntpdc` command to standard output:

```
if ntpdc -n -c monlist $SERVER 2>&1 | grep "timed out"
then 
  echo "Server won't let You use monlist."
  exit 0
else 
  echo "Server will let You use monlist."
fi
```